Flutter Xcode macOS project built successfully but run error: Code has restricted entitlements, but the validation of its code signature failed
I'm building Flutter project in macOS. Actually everything works and not sure why one day I can build in Xcode but crashed on starting the app.

The entire error message is below
Could not launch “Transmission”
Domain: IDELaunchErrorDomain
Code: 20
Recovery Suggestion: Runningboard has returned error 5. Please check the system logs for the underlying cause of the error.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-07-18 02:20:55 +0000";
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 968756;
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchServicesLauncher;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. Launch failed.
Domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: Launch failed.
--
Launchd job spawn failed
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 162
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_identifier" = "00006000-001231E00AD2801E";
    "device_model" = "MacBookPro18,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.0 (24A5279h)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.macosx";
    "device_thinningType" = "MacBookPro18,1";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "397.3.5.2";
    "dvt_coresimulator_version" = 980;
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1759.0.4";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 51;
    "operation_errorCode" = 20;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDELaunchErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchServicesLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.macosx";
    "param_diag_113575882_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 2;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 99;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "macosx15.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.0";
    "sdk_variant" = macos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 15.0 (Build 24A5279h)
Xcode 16.0 (23037.4) (Build 16A5171r)
Timestamp: 2024-07-18T10:20:55+08:00

And I checked console of system, I got these errors

One of the key messages should be related
AMFI: When validating /Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cqdxcabvgjbudueiqbiffjdrzyee/Build/Products/Debug/Transmission.app/Contents/MacOS/Transmission:
  Code has restricted entitlements, but the validation of its code signature failed.
Unsatisfied Entitlements:

Here's the output of flutter doctor
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.1, on macOS 15.0 24A5279h darwin-arm64, locale zh-Hans-HK)
    • Flutter version 3.22.1 on channel stable at /Users/jonathan/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision a14f74ff3a (8 weeks ago), 2024-05-22 11:08:21 -0500
    • Engine revision 55eae6864b
    • Dart version 3.4.1
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jonathan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/jonathan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 16A5171r
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.92.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Jonathan‘s iPhone (mobile)      • 00008120-001429A42268C01E • ios          • iOS 18.0 22A5307i
    • macOS (desktop)                 • macos                     • darwin-arm64 • macOS 15.0 24A5279h darwin-arm64
    • Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad     • darwin       • macOS 15.0 24A5279h darwin-arm64
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for 李展威的Apple Watch. Ensure the device is unlocked and discoverable via Bluetooth. (code -27)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for Jonathan‘s iPad Pro. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area network as
      this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for Yehosua’s iPhone. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area network as this
      Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

